# Is it possible to identify the carrier / operator (ATT, Verizon, etc.) from the Android User Agent String

Tags: android, web-applications, mobile-phones, carrier

Server Side I need to identify the carrier (ATT, Verizon, etc.).

On iPhone you can do it with the firmware number.  I was thinking that Android's device + build information in the UA might do the trick.

Has anyone done this.  I do not have client side access so Telephony Manager is not an option.

Comment: How about adding a custom header?

Comment: You do realize that international users might have the same firmware for different carriers, right? I don't think this will ever be possible unless you have ONLY US users and can guarantee that no one buys their devices without a contract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, User Agent won't do the trick.

You can get the carrier/network information for any device by using a geolocation service.

For at least one service that provides that level of detail, look at the answer to this similar question:
[How to determine if incoming IP address is from a mobile carrier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256939/how-to-determine-if-incoming-ip-address-is-from-a-mobile-carrier)

You can probably find more.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that.  Geolocation service and mobile carrier IP address reverse lookup does partially solve the problem.  It falls short if the device is connected over Wi-Fi.

Comment: True, and a device connected over wifi may not have a cellular carrier, so you're stuck.