# Redirect mobile users based on country and carrier

Tags: php, jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

Anyone knows a easy way preferably PHP to achieve this. I want to redirect mobile visitors based on their country and carrier (like T-mobile or Vodafone). Thanks in advance

Comment: Partial answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256939/how-to-determine-if-incoming-ip-address-is-from-a-mobile-carrier

Answer (score 3):

There is a HTML5 Network Information API:

- http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/dap/raw-file/tip/network-api/index.html

Not sure if you can get Carrier information though but I know some Carriers offer HTML5 API's of there own that you might take advantage of:

- http://developer.att.com/developer/forward.jsp?passedItemId=9700222

Also there is a HTML5 Geolocation API

- http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html

More Examples:

- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/optimization-and-performance/

As for a PHP solution you could do a carrier lookup, there are no free solutions but you can try something like this:

- http://www.data24-7.com/carrier24-7.php

But for this to work you would need to obtain the users phone number which:

1. [HTML5 thankfully can not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738243/get-users-number-from-iphone-using-html5-jquery)
2. [PHP thankfully can not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103509/php-script-to-get-mobile-number)

The user would have to manually enter the number or develop a native app which would have access to the device number

Comment: @vinny if this answered your question, please select it as the answer . Glad to help